# Do I need a visa to transit India?

Tags: india, transit-visas, bulgarian-citizens

I am Bulgarian passport holder, travelling from Dubai to Kuala Lumpur (to and from) via Delhi and Mumbai with layovers of 2-4 hours. The flights are with Jet Airways and Malaysian Airlines.

Do I need an airport transit visa for India?

Comment: @pnuts, I realise that website says so, but two weeks ago I transited in Chennai and didn't need a visa (citizenship was irrelevant, I wasn't even checked, just put through bag security a couple of times).  I'm not putting as an answer as other airports may be different, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 1):

According to [TimaticWeb](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=BG&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=MY&EM=AE&TR=IN&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C):

> Visa required, except for Holders of an Overseas Citizen of India Card or Booklet, or:
>
> Visa required, except for Holders of a
>   Person of Indian Origin (PIO) Card, or:
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Visa required, **except for Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours**.
>
> Hotel facilities are available in Terminal 3 at Delhi (DEL), provided holding boarding card for connecting flight.

Therefore you won't need a transit visa since your layover is shorter than 24 hours.