# Customs and immigration clearance transiting at DEL

Tags: transit, india, us-citizens, del

Does an American citizen traveling from New York to Kathmandu via Delhi need to clear customs and immigration if holding a boarding pass to the final destination? Can he access the transit hotel in the airport without a visa?

Answer (score 1):

If you already hold the onward boarding pass, you do not need to pass immigration as India allows Transit Without Visa. See [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/14303/50234) for a first hand account. Even if you need to collect luggage at DEL, there are anecdotes of airlines doing it for you (See [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77743/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-india-if-i-need-to-re-check-my-luggage/77788#77788)).

The airport hotel is accessible to transit passengers without an Indian visa. From the [website](http://www.newdelhiairport.in/airport-hotel.aspx) (Emphasis mine)

> **Valid International Airline Boarding Pass for onward journey is
>   mandatory** to access the International Wing. **INDIAN VISA is not a
>   prerequisite** for passenger coming from an International Destination
>   transiting through Delhi to next International Destination. Checked-in
>   luggage transfer is responsibility of the respective airlines and
>   information regarding the same can be obtained at the International
>   Transfer Desk. Passenger can access the hotel with hand luggage after
>   security check. The International Wing is located at on the 5th Floor
>   accessible from the International Retail area. Transit Passengers can
>   access our hotel after crossing the International Transfer desk
>   followed by security check.

It also has this piece of advice for transit passengers (emphasis mine)

> **Passengers coming from International Destination and transit through
>   Delhi to next International Destination are requested to book the
>   International wing**. **Guests do not need an INDIAN VISA**. Guests will
>   need to have a valid boarding pass to stay at the hotel.The maximum
>   length of stay for any guest cannot exceed 24 hours and hence the
>   hotel would be able to provide a room only 24 hours prior to the
>   guest's flight. **Please note that once the guest checks-in to the
>   hotel, they are not allowed to leave the hotel premises.**

This info is also provided by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=US&PASSTYPES=PASS&AR=00&DE=NP&selDest=Nepal&TR=IN&selTrans=India&user=PYB2C&subuser=PYB2C)

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Visa required, except for Holders of
>   confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.
>   - Hotel facilities are available in Terminal 3 at Delhi (DEL) if holding a boarding card for the connecting flight.