# As an Indian citizen, can I exit Delhi airport during a 9-hour long transit?

Tags: transit, india, turkish-airlines, new-delhi, air-india

I am an Indian citizen travelling from Istanbul to Kolkata. I have booked with Turkish Airlines. My Istanbul-Delhi leg is with Indigo and I arrive in Delhi at 05:00. And then my Delhi-Kolkata leg is with Air India departing at 14:00. The entire journey has a single PNR.

Is it possible to exit Delhi airport for the duration of my transit? Is there like a special procedure to be followed for that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes**, you can exit the airport freely.  You will clear Indian immigration & customs at Delhi, after which you can choose to stay in the terminal (both your arriving and departing flights are to/from Terminal 3) or continue anywhere else in Delhi.

Comment: but given that it is a single booking I will receive my baggage in Kolkatta so I think customs is not possible in Delhi.

Comment: @k_parida You will collect your bags at Delhi, take them through Customs, and then recheck them for your connecting flight.

Comment: @jpatokal, can you explain this last comment please? As op says, on a connected flight you usually get the bags when the whole flight is finished, you do not keep getting/checking them in after each leg. What indicates, that in op's case that's what would happen?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh They are flying internationally into India, so immigration & customs happens at the port of entry, namely Delhi.  See this Q&A for more detail: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108529/how-to-handle-checked-baggage-when-transiting-international-to-domestic-at-del